# How can I change http session timeout for web service endpoint of an stateless EJB?

Tags: java, ejb

I have an stateless EJB and I've defined a web service endpoint for it by annotation @WebService (as seen below). I manage authentication and session using HTTP session and by using WebServiceContext. The code works OK.

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class UserManager implements UserManagerRemote{
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

    @Override @WebMethod
    public boolean login(String username, String password){
        if(!checkUser(username, password))
            return false;
        HttpSession session = HttpServletRequest)webServiceContext.getMessageContext().
                   get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        return true;
    }

    @Override @WebMethod
    public int doSomthing(){
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)webServiceContext.getMessageContext().
            get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
        if(session == null)
            return -1;
        //do the thing and return the result
        return 1;
    }

}
```

What I need to do is changing the timeout of http session for the EJB webservice endpoint. I've tried every thing, but since the program deploys as ejb-jar on glassfish, there is no web.xml. How can I change the http session timeout for EJB web service endpoint?
P.S. I cant use Stateful EJB because I'm going to use web service endpoint.

Comment: How about packaging it as a WAR?

Comment: The packaging structure is EAR, it contains a WAR file for another purpose. I changed the session timeout in the WAR but didnt work for EJB

Comment: Is there really a session created at all?

Comment: Yes, when you access HttpSession, automatically a session is created for web service client. (web service client should enable cookies)

Comment: Still, why dont you package it as a WAR? An EAR can contain multiple WARs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solve it! I couldnt find any global parameter for changing session time out but it can be changed for each individual session through HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval) . Although based on [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) this method gets interval in seconds, but it worked by milliseconds apparently.